# Is there any setting available in Mule such that error in one flow would not cause Mule to shut down completely?

Tags: mule

Whenever there is some problem in a Mule flow, for example using an HTTPS url in the HTTP connector, Mule throws fatal error, and shuts down. Is there any way to configure Mule such that it will not start the erroneous flow, but start all other flows and does not shut down completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to make Mule ignore configuration errors. And if you ask me, I'd say it's a good thing. Your configuration should be valid at all times.

Of course, this has nothing to do with letting Mule start with failed connections (like for example start even if a remote JMS broker is down). In that case the reconnection strategy is what you need to configure to let Mule start and try to reconnect until successful.

But it the case of a wrong configuration, there's no hope to eventually reconnect so IMO Mule's early death at startup is the most sane approach.

Comment: But when only one flow has configuration problem, doesn't it make sense to start Mule with all other good flows and just terminate the erroneous flow? At least the application would not stop abruptly when somebody makes a mistake as small as a spelling error. (Typing htpp instead of http in an http connector causes Mule to shut down completely, which is not graceful according to me.)

Comment: I guess we have a different point of view then. As a comparison, try to make an error in a bean name in a Spring configuration and start the application. It seems others find value in a fail-fast approach to configuration validation.